# Getting a fixed footer to expand height from top to bottom on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have a [page - here](http://dirtybirddesignlab.com/TLC/WebsiteV4A/index.php) with a fixed footer. The main content `#mid.stages > .stages` scrolls behind the footer, and using jQuery waypoints when you scroll to the bottom of the page the footer needs to gain height (from top down) and the section `#topFooter` needs to expand from the top down to reveal its contents. I have been trying various solutions to no avail, namely due to the fact that when initially loaded the footer has a fixed position and the 'reveal' part of it is outside the browser window.

```
    $(function(){
        var position = function () {
            var w = $(window).height();
            //var f = $('footer').height();
            var foo = (w-110);
            console.log(foo);
            $('footer').css('top', foo);
        };
        $(document).ready(position);
        $(window).resize(position);

        $('#mid').waypoint(function(direction) {
            var stagePOS = $('.stage').position();
            if (direction === 'down') {
                //$('footer').animate({height:'600px', top:'stagePOS.top'},300,'swing', position);
                $('footer').css({'position':'absolute', 'height':'600px','top':'stagePOS.top'});
                $('.tfContent').css({'height':'200px'});
                $('p.extra').fadeIn('fast');
            } else if (direction === 'up') {
                $('footer').css({'position':'fixed','top':'foo'});
                $('.tfContent').css({'height':'60px'});
                $('p.extra').slideUp('fast');
            }
            position();
        }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
    });
```

I need the footer to expand from the top down, so it doesn't cover up the content in `#mid.stages > .stages`, pretty much the opposite of what I have now, and be able to use some sort of animation so it's not so choppy as it is now. Any push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are referring to some variables in between quotes. You need to remove those quotes. 
In the following lines:

```
$('footer').css({'position':'absolute', 'height':'600px','top':stagePOS.top});
```

In this line also I don't see a variable foo, the only one I see is defined inside the position function. Unless you have it somewhere else in your code, you need to replace it with the calculation:

```
$('footer').css({'position':'fixed','top':$(window).height()-110});
```

Also, I noticed you set the top of the footer to be the top of the first stage element and that's why it grows upwards and covers the content. I would suggest trying to make the footer position relative, height of 60px and animate growth to 600px. So it will stay below the content and the page will grow to contain it.

```
$('footer').css({'position':'relative', 'height':'60px'}).animate({'height':'600px'}, 400) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I have your last suggestion running now, but has some unexpected consequences - it inserts a ton of space - guessing I need to recalculate the 'top' property?

Comment: Try setting top property to auto.

Comment: Or position to static instead of relative, check here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: ({'position':'static', 'top':'auto'}) seems like the way to go, thanks man. Great stuff.